# Nautilus seems to be very slow only when I use the "Faenza" theme

Tags: nautilus, themes

I'm using gnome-shell and all seems to be good but I've only one problem. Nautilus seems to be very slow only when I use the theme "Faenza", with other theme is all great. In particular Nautilus is slow when switching from one Nautilus window to another the gtk is slow to load and i have to wait about 1-2 seconds before the right colours are shown.

How can I fix it? Has anyone had problems like this? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, Gnome-Shell 3.6.2 and Nautilus 3.6.3.

Comment: I've used this ppa ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu

Comment: If anyone thinks he knows just what may be the problem (not the solution) do not hesitate to comment!

Comment: I installed it and use gnome-tweak to change the icon theme. Do not feel any slowness with nautilus. Check ~/.xsession-errors to see if there are any info. (gnome-shell 3.4.1-0ubuntu2, nautilus 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu6)

Comment: The problem is not the icon theme but the gtk theme. With any other theme (gtk) nautilus go fast. I don't know what is the problem, but it keeps me awake at night, it makes no sense. I don't know how to post the file ~/.xsession-errors because is very huge.

Comment: It is safe to delete ~/.xsession-errors. Then logout and login, open nautilus, and check what is in xsession-erros.

Comment: I've done what you say but the file has not been created. This means that Nautilus has no problems?

Comment: That is correct. xsession-error mostly contain x windows related issue like x/gtk library error/complaint. On the other hand, Faenza actually come with icon theme matching popular desktop theme like `Faenza-Radiance`, `Faenza-Ambiance`. Did you try those? Additional question, does the slowness happen if nautilus is displaying specific folders or any folder? Maybe it is because the folder is just huge to update/reflesh all the icons?!

Comment: Maybe the problem is the GTK (or even the window) theme

Comment: A comment [here](http://design.canonical.com/2010/08/an-update-to-the-ubuntu-light-themes/) by Geliy seems to suggest it may have to do with the theme's transparent menus; that might be something to look into. In any case, I recommend opening a Terminal window and running `top` or `htop`. Either is a lightweight way to monitor what processes are using the most CPU and memory. Those aren't the only relevant resources...but they are important; I suspect CPU is the resource that's running out here.

Comment: Then perform actions that usually trigger slowdown, and look to see if any processes are markedly increasing their CPU usage (and/or markedly changing, probably increasing, in their *memory usage*--sometimes the need to *allocate* more memory for a process slows the system down).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Ubuntu tweak's janitor tool to clean the old packages, icons and cache from cruft. It could be because of too much cache. Your problem is very unique and is not an general issue. Try my suggestion it might help